# Tuples and MSVC Compiler in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, tuples

I'm trying to compile this example in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
 
std::tuple<double, char, std::string> get_student(int id)
{
    if (id == 0) return std::make_tuple(3.8, 'A', std::string("Lisa Simpson"));
    if (id == 1) return std::make_tuple(2.9, 'C', std::string("Milhouse Van Houten"));
    if (id == 2) return std::make_tuple(1.7, 'D', std::string("Ralph Wiggum"));
    throw std::invalid_argument("id");
}
 
int main()
{
    auto student0 = get_student(0);
    std::cout << "ID: 0, "
              << "GPA: " << std::get<0>(student0) << ", "
              << "grade: " << std::get<1>(student0) << ", "
              << "name: " << std::get<2>(student0) << '\n';
 
    double gpa1;
    char grade1;
    std::string name1;
    std::tie(gpa1, grade1, name1) = get_student(1);
    std::cout << "ID: 1, "
              << "GPA: " << gpa1 << ", "
              << "grade: " << grade1 << ", "
              << "name: " << name1 << '\n';
 
    // C++17 structured binding:
    auto [ gpa2, grade2, name2 ] = get_student(2);
    std::cout << "ID: 2, "
              << "GPA: " << gpa2 << ", "
              << "grade: " << grade2 << ", "
              << "name: " << name2 << '\n';
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.15.1 with MSVC2019 64 bit compiler. It gives me these errors for the second and third `make_tuple`s:

```
main.cpp:9:22: error: no matching function for call to 'make_tuple'
tuple:888:53: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Types = <double, char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >>]
```

when I change to MinGW these errors will go away.

Why am I getting these errors? Any solution?

Comment: Can you try in a smaller example if any call to std::make_tuple works? It seems strange that line 8 works and line 9 suddenly not

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. The code compiles in both Qt and Visual Studio 2022. Those errors seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error . In VS I dont get those red lines.

Comment: I believe its CLang code model causing those errors.

Comment: It seems you need to add `CONFIG += c++11` in your .pro file.

Comment: I have added c++17. @AlexanderDyagilev

Comment: Those error messages are not produced by MSVC. MSVC would emit something like `error C1234: message`, complete with the error code (not necessarily 1234 of course, that's just for example).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes you are right. I believe its Clang Code Model in QtCreator add-ons causing this.